# PHP date difference extremly hard to accomplish

Tags: php

I have to get back dates just subtracting days from the current date and time.

Let suppose current date is May 1, 2011

after subtracting 30 days

April 1, 2011

How to accomplish this in PHP? Please help

Comment: please point out why none of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=date+difference+php solved your problem. It's not like this is a rather original question and hasnt been asked dozens of time before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$unixtime = strtotime("May 1, 2011 -30 days");
$human_readable = date('F j, Y', $unixtime);
```

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on Emil's answer. You can one-line it like so:

```
$thirty_days_ago = date('F j, Y', strtotime('-30 days'));
```

If you leave out the "May 1, 2011" part in strtotime(), you'll get 30 days ago from whatever the current date is.

Also, you've got a number of options for formatting [in the docs](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).